# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at String.replace (<anonymous>) -- I am unable to resolve this error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Bootstrap 4 to make a tab slider and I want to handle the tabs from the top, bottom, left & right clicks. I wrote codes in jquery to do the same.  But getting the RangeError like above as mentioned in the question title.

When I comment the jquery code related to **Lower Tabs**, it works perfectly for the top, left & right click, but the lower tabs don't work in the way as I want. Please find out the solution for me. Thanks in Advance...

HTML is as below:-

```
<body>
<h1 class="my-5 text-center">Tab Slider</h1>
    <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs my-tab upper">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Tab 4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab5">Tab 5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
              <h1>This is Tab 1</h1>
              <p>This is the paragraph for Tab 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
              <h1>This is Tab 2</h1>
              <p>This is the paragraph for Tab 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
              <h1>This is Tab 3</h1>
              <p>This is the paragraph for Tab 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4">
              <h1>This is Tab 4</h1>
              <p>This is the paragraph for Tab 4</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab5">
              <h1>This is Tab 5</h1>
              <p>This is the paragraph for Tab 5</p>
            </div>

            <button class="tab-navigate tab-prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
            <button class="tab-navigate tab-next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
          </div>
          
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs my-tab lower">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Tab 4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab5">Tab 5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
</body>
```

CSS code is:-

```
.my-tab.upper {
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
}
.my-tab.upper .nav-link {
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}
.my-tab.upper .nav-item.show .nav-link, .my-tab.upper .nav-link.active {
    border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
}
.my-tab.lower {
    border-top: 3px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
.my-tab.lower .nav-item.show .nav-link, .my-tab.lower .nav-link.active {
    border-top: 5px solid blue;
}
.my-tab .nav-item.show .nav-link, .my-tab .nav-link.active {
    color: blue;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.my-tab .nav-link {
    border: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'GothamProNarrow-Bold';
    font-size: 16px;
}
.tab-prev {
    left: -75px;
}
.tab-navigate {
    outline: 0;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 42px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    color: blue;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
.tab-next {
    right: -75px;
}
```

Jquery code is:-

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var tabsUpper = $(".my-tab.upper");
        var tabsLower = $(".my-tab.lower");

        var $tabsUpperLinks = $(".my-tab.upper").find(".nav-link");
        var $tabsLowerLinks = $(".my-tab.lower").find(".nav-link");

         //When click on Upper Tabs
        for(let i = 0; i < $tabsUpperLinks.length; i++){
          let clickedUpperLink = $($tabsUpperLinks[i]);
          clickedUpperLink.on("click", function(e){
            let clickedLowerLink = $($tabsLowerLinks[i])
            clickedLowerLink.click();
            return;
          });
        }

          //When click on Lower Tabs
             for(let j = 0; j < $tabsLowerLinks.length; j++){
          let lowerLink = $($tabsLowerLinks[j]);
          lowerLink.on("click", function(){
            let upperLink = $($tabsUpperLinks[j])
            upperLink.click();
            return;
          });
        }

        //When click for next tab
        $(".tab-next").on("click", function(){
          $.each(tabsUpper, function(index, value){
            let $navItems = $(this).find(".nav-link");
            let navItemsLength = $navItems.length;
            
            for(let i = 0; i < navItemsLength; i++){
              let activeTabLink = $($navItems[i]);
              if(activeTabLink.hasClass("active")){
                 nextTabLink = $($navItems[i+1]);
                 if(i == navItemsLength-1){
                  nextTabLink = $($navItems[0]);
                 }
                 activeTabLink.removeClass("active");
                 nextTabLink.click();
                 return;
              }
            }
          });
        });

         //When click for previous tab
        $(".tab-prev").on("click", function(){
          $.each(tabsUpper, function(index, value){
            let $navItems = $(this).find(".nav-link");
            let navItemsLength = $navItems.length;
            
            for(let i = navItemsLength-1; i >= 0; i--){
              let activeTabLink = $($navItems[i]);
              if(activeTabLink.hasClass("active")){
                 prevTabLink = $($navItems[i-1]);
                 if(i == 0){
                  prevTabLink = $($navItems[navItemsLength-1]);
                 }
                 activeTabLink.removeClass("active");
                 prevTabLink.click();
                 return;
              }
            }   
          });
        });
      });
```

Comment: When you click on upper link, you select all the lower links and raise click event on them - which raises click event on all the upper links ... which raises click event on all the lower links... etc.  It's not clear what you're *trying* to do.

Comment: I want to change the middle content **(Tab Content)** by clicking either of the tabs from the top tab or the bottom tab. For example, if I click on Tab 3 Upper, then obviously the Tab 3 Lower should also be active, and if click on Tab 5 Upper, then Tab 5 Lower should get active and so on...Also, the left and right clicks are there to go the next or previous tab. I know that my codes need to be modified, that's why I am asking here...

Comment: @freedomn-m When I comment the jquery code of **Lower Tabs**, then everything works fine. But I also want lower tabs to work in the same way as upper tabs. You can observe the tabs by commenting the codes related to **Lower Tabs**.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code:

```js
        $('.tab-prev').on('click',function(){
        var idOfActive = $('.nav-link.active').eq(0).attr('id');
        var indexOfActive=parseInt(idOfActive.replaceAll('tab','').replaceAll('-btn','').replaceAll('-up',''));
        
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()+'-up-btn').removeClass('active');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()).removeClass('active');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()).removeClass('show');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()+'-up-btn').attr('tabindex','-1');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()+'-up-btn').attr('aria-selected','false');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()).attr('aria-selected','false');
        indexOfActive--;
        if(indexOfActive==0)
            indexOfActive=5;
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()).addClass('active');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()).addClass('show');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()+'-up-btn').addClass('active');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()+'-up-btn').removeAttr('tabindex');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()+'-up-btn').attr('aria-selected','true');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()+'-up-btn').trigger('click');
        })
        $('.tab-next').on('click',function(){
        var idOfActive = $('.nav-link.active').eq(0).attr('id');
        var indexOfActive=parseInt(idOfActive.replaceAll('tab','').replaceAll('-btn','').replaceAll('-up',''));
        
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()+'-up-btn').removeClass('active');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()).removeClass('active');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()).removeClass('show');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()+'-up-btn').attr('tabindex','-1');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()+'-up-btn').attr('aria-selected','false');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()).attr('aria-selected','false');
        indexOfActive++;
        if(indexOfActive==6)
            indexOfActive=1;
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()).addClass('active');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()).addClass('show');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()+'-up-btn').addClass('active');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()+'-up-btn').removeAttr('tabindex');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()+'-up-btn').attr('aria-selected','true');
        $('#tab'+indexOfActive.toString()+'-up-btn').trigger('click');
        })
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="my-5 text-center">Tab Slider</h1>
    <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs my-tab upper">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="tab1-up-btn" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab1"  role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="tab2-up-btn" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab2"  role="tab" aria-controls="tab2" aria-selected="false">Tab 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="tab3-up-btn" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab3"  role="tab" aria-controls="tab3" aria-selected="false">Tab 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="tab4-up-btn" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab4"  role="tab" aria-controls="tab4" aria-selected="false">Tab 4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="tab5-up-btn" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab5"  role="tab" aria-controls="tab5" aria-selected="false">Tab 5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
              <h1>This is Tab 1</h1>
              <p>This is the paragraph for Tab 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
              <h1>This is Tab 2</h1>
              <p>This is the paragraph for Tab 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
              <h1>This is Tab 3</h1>
              <p>This is the paragraph for Tab 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4">
              <h1>This is Tab 4</h1>
              <p>This is the paragraph for Tab 4</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab5">
              <h1>This is Tab 5</h1>
              <p>This is the paragraph for Tab 5</p>
            </div>

            <button class="tab-navigate tab-prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
            <button class="tab-navigate tab-next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
          </div>
          
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs my-tab lower">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="tab1-btn" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab1"  role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="tab2-btn" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab2"  role="tab" aria-controls="tab2" aria-selected="false">Tab 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="tab3-btn" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab3"  role="tab" aria-controls="tab3" aria-selected="false">Tab 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="tab4-btn" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab4"  role="tab" aria-controls="tab4" aria-selected="false">Tab 4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="tab5-btn" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tab5"  role="tab" aria-controls="tab5" aria-selected="false">Tab 5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>

        </script>
        
</body>
</html>
```